# In Cypress how to check if the element contains the specific text

Tags: cucumber, cypress

In Cypress how to check if the element contains the specific text
Eg. In search box I have entered some name ( pav)

Drop-down list displayed with some options( eg. Mayuk pavi S )

Here the name contains pav. And it should pass  .
Need to check this scenario

Need to checke whether the drop-down lists contains the specific text or not

Comment: Can you show some relevant html of your dropdown list? Are they normal html <option> tags? If they are simple options, you may use `cy.contains('option','pav').should('exist');`, and if you want' select it, you may use `cy.contains('option','pav').click();`

Comment: Add the code you tried.

Comment: @art Thanks.. I need to check if the word 'pav' is exists in all the drop-down lists (mayuk 'pav'i S, oru 'pav'r H)

Comment: @AlapanDas the code I have tried cy get('element')cy.contains('pav')

Answer (score 4):

Checking all the option in the dropdown requires [.each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each) command.

First use `.find()` to pick all the option elements

Something like this test would confirm that the text you search for is contained in every dropdown option -

```js
const searchText = 'pav'
cy.get('#search').type(searchText)

cy.get('#search-options').find('option')
  .each($option => {
    cy.wrap($option).should('contain', searchText)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

For overall search:

```
cy.contains('pav')
```

To search in a specific element:

```
cy.get(elem).contains('pav')
```

here "elem" is your element selector

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it depends on what you want. I would need to see some code, but I can give some general insight:

If you want a tests to check if the element contains certain text:

```
cy.get('your HTML element here').contains('your text here');
```

If you want to do something conditionally if the text exists, you would do something like this:

```
cy.get('body').then($body =>
    if ($body.find('your HTML element here').contains('your text here')) { 
        cy.get("your HTML element here").then($el => {
            if ($el.is(':visible')){
                // do something if element contains text and visible
            } else{
                // do something if element contains text and is not
            }
        });
    }
});
```